# looping through dynamic variable names

Tags: loops, macros, spss

I want to be able to loop through a series of similarly named variables in SPSS, just changing a few parameters. For example, i have variables

q7_22_react_a
q7_22_react_b
q7_22_react_c
q7_2**3**_react_a
q7_2**3**_react_b
q7_2**3**_react_c

Notice the numbering and letter changes. I tried this but it's not parsing the "7_22" very well:

```
define !test (numbers= !chardend('/') / letters= !cmdend).
!do !i !in (!numbers)
   frequencies variables !concat(q,!i,'_react_',!letters)
!doend
!enddefine.

!test numbers= 7_22 / letters= a.
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Nice one! haven't run across this before... I checked some more and found that tokens get split up if they start with a number or with an underscore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's a real solution, but I can think of a couple of workarounds. The Idea would be to prevent the token from getting split up - either by starting it with a letter:

```
define !test2 (numbers= !chardend('/') / letters= !cmdend).
!do !i !in (!numbers)
   frequencies variables !concat(!i,'_react_',!letters)
!doend
!enddefine.

!test2 numbers= q7_22 / letters= a.
```

or by adding quotes:

```
define !test3 (numbers= !chardend('/') / letters= !cmdend).
!do !i !in (!numbers)
   frequencies variables !concat('q',!unquote(!i),'_react_',!letters)
!doend
!enddefine.

!test3 numbers= '7_22' / letters= a.
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried and succeed with a similar workaround with the naming conventions.

I stumbled on an old IBM thread and it looks like when there are underscores in the macro lists SPSS will separate it as different variables. A real pain, but solvable.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution.

```
SPSSINC SELECT VARIABLES MACRONAME="!react"
/PROPERTIES  PATTERN = ".*react".

freq !react.
```

The pattern is a regular expression - here any name that includes "react".
The SPSSINC SELECT VARIABLES is an extension command normally installed with Statistics in recent versions or available from the SPSS Community site.  It has a dialog box that appears on the Utilities menu

Answer (score 1):

```
define !test (numbers= !chardend('/') / letters= !cmdend).
    !do !i !in (!numbers)
       frequencies variables !concat(q,!UNQUOTE(!i),'_react_',!letters).
    !doend
!enddefine.
SET MPRINT ON.
!test numbers= '7_22' / letters= a.

Resulting Syntax ;-)))
frequencies variables q7_22_react_a.
```